# Multiple Threads calling same function causes problems

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to remake a Monopoly type game in C# for simulation purposes.
I use threads to simulate multiple games simultaneously. Basically i am just creating a loop that starts a new thread, calling my GameLoop function with a new Game object for storing players, the board and the Game ID. When i start it using only one thread, the game works just fine, when i use multiple however, it seems like the threads are somehow changing the Position data of each other what at some point, causes the game to crash because of negative positions (i suppose).

My Code as of right now looks like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace monopoly_stats
{
    public class Launcher
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrepareGame();
        }

        private static void PrepareGame()
        {
            
            // Instantiate Lists for Players and fields
            List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
            List<Field> fields = new List<Field>();
            Board board = null;

            //new Field(price, housePrice, rent, rent1House, rent2House, rent3House, rent4House, rentHotel, name, type, upgradeStage, available)
            // Just adding some fields for testing purposes
            fields.Add(new Field(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Los", "go"));
            fields.Add(new Field(60, 50, 6, 10, 20, 30, 40, 70, "Badstraße"));
            fields.Add(new Field(60, 50, 6, 10, 20, 30, 40, 70, "Turmstraße"));
            fields.Add(new Field(60, 50, 6, 10, 20, 30, 40, 70, "Chausseestraße"));
            fields.Add(new Field(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Gefängnis", "jail"));

            // Instantiate Instances of Player and Board Classes 
            while(true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type name of new Player, leave blank to confirm: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                if(name != "")
                {
                    // Add new Player to players list
                    players.Add(new Player(name));
                    Console.WriteLine("Player {0} added!", name);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach(Player p in players)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Saved Player {0}", p.Name);
                    }
                    foreach(Field f in fields)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Saved Field {0}", f.Name);
                    }
                    // Create Instance of Board class to store players and fields
                    board = new Board(players, fields);
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Prompt user to enter number of threads
            Console.WriteLine("How many games should be simulated?");
            int numThreads = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Create the desired Number of threads
            for(int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting Thread {0}", i+1);
                var threadStart = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                var thread = new Thread(
                    () =>
                    {
                        threadStart.Set();
                        GameLoop(new Game(i, board, players));
                    });
                
                // Start the Thread & wait
                thread.Start();
                threadStart.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        // Main Game Loop
        private static void GameLoop(Game game)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread with ID [{0}] Successfully started", game.Id);
            // Infinite loop
            while(true)
            {
                // Perform needed actions for player movement (not finished)
                foreach(Player p in game.Players)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("[Thread {0}] It's {1}'s turn", game.Id, p.Name);
                    p.Move();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also noticed that it seems to work better when i implement a Thread.Sleep() into the movement function of the players, but i think the movement is still wrong in this case.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you expecting the threads to 'take turns' on their own? They don't. Both threads run concurrently and both try to change the same data. They will 'stomp' on each other. Your program's code needs to implement synchronization between the threads inside the `GameLoop()` or inside the Player `Move()`.

Comment: Is it somehow possible for them to not change the same data?

Comment: In many situations with threads, you can give each thread its own data to work with. Here it looks like each thread represents a `Player` and the `Player`s are sharing a `Board`. Do you want the `Player` threads to take turns modifying a shared `Board`?

Comment: If the case is two `Player`s sharing a `Board`, then consider how to design the code so that a `Player` might acquire exclusive access to the `Board` at the beginning of a 'turn', make a move, and release exclusive access at the end of the 'turn'.

Comment: No, i want every thread to be it's own game. The GameLoop Function itself has all functionality to play a game of monopoly on itself.

Comment: It looks like you are reusing and thus sharing the `players` and the `fields`. But you don't show the `Board` constructor and you don't show `Player.Move()`, so that is a guess

Comment: Create a class that represents a game (all the state). Instantiate a game object for each game and hand it to a game runner object (that has _no_state of its own). When you get tired of using the console as your UI, make sure that you have a separate UI thread, and that each game runner is careful to marshal UI operations to the UI thread

Comment: In very broad strokes with the existing code, in the `PrepareGame()` method take the code starting at the `//Prompt user to enter number of threads` comment to the end of the method and move it to a new method. In `Main` call the new method. In the new method call `PrepareGame()` for each thread.

Comment: @TitusTesche - There's a race condition on the `i` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition.

Try this code:

```
var list = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var threadStart = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    var thread = new Thread( () =>
    {
        threadStart.Set();
        list.Add(i);
    });
    thread.Start();
    threadStart.WaitOne();
}
Console.WriteLine(
    list
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
        .Any());
```

When you run this multiple times you'll get either `True` or `False` to the console.

What's happening is after the `threadStart.Set();` you're sometimes getting a thread interrupt before the `GameLoop(new Game(i, board, players));` which is allowing the `i` to increment before the call. You're effectively missing some `i` and duplicating others.

Two simple solutions can be done. I'll show you those on my sample program.

(1) Change the order of the commands:

```
        list.Add(i);
        threadStart.Set();
```

(2) Capture the `i` in the loop and use that.

```
        int j = i;
        threadStart.Set();
        list.Add(j);
```

Both solve the race condition.